# Terminal app no longer automatically recognizes functions in my ~/.profile any more

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I made some function in my ~/.profile to automate things like SSH connections.  They were working fine until recently.  Now I need to "run" the ~/.profile by doing `. .profile` each time I open Terminal for my functions to work.  How can fix this to make the functions available at start automatically?

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `~/.bash_profile` exist?

If both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` exist, bash reads only `~/.bash_profile` when it is invoked as an interactive login shell.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html:

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.